# this is my popuppanel's occurence code.....but it only works 1 time

Tags: gwt

```
popup.setPopupPositionAndShow(new PopupPanel.PositionCallback() {
    public void setPosition(int offsetWidth, int offsetHeight) {
        int r = getToothNumber();
        if(r == 14 || r == 15 || r == 16) {
            popup.setPopupPosition(event.getClientX() - 170, event.getClientY());
            popup.show();
        } else if(r > 16) {
            popup.setPopupPosition(event.getClientX() - 56, event.getClientY() - 550);
            popup.show();
        } else {
            popup.setPopupPosition(event.getClientX() + 22, event.getClientY());
            popup.show();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Add more details to your questions to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should always show a popup. The problem is probably not in the code you are showing. My guess is that you are not simply hiding popup. You might be destroying it, in which case a show() will not work. Please try to always create a new popup and not reuse it.